# Arabic characters in String.Format("%d",1,Locale.US)

Tags: java, android

I have the following code:

```
private static final String PATTERN = "file_%d.txt";
int no; // 1-3
String filename = String.format(PATTERN, no ,Locale.US);
```

and later on I get an exception saying that

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file_٣.txt
```

which indicates that %d got replaced with an arabic number. How can that be if I explicitely specify Locale.US?

Comment: Isn't this the function you should use: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#format(java.util.Locale, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...)

Comment: +1. I had no idea %d could do that.

Comment: Yes! I was right :P Check Thilo's answer. You function is correct because Locale.US was considered the second argument for the formatted String, when in fact, your locale should have been the first argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The locale needs to be the first parameter:

```
 String.format(Locale.US,PATTERN, no);
```